# Where was Rufus Scrimgeour before Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince, and what was he doing?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, when Fudge went with Dolores Umbridge to arrest Dumbledore for supposedly setting up the "Dumbledore's Army", Fudge brought 2 Aurors (Dawlish and Shacklebolt) with him.  Why didn't Fudge bring Rufus Scrimgeour, as the latter was supposed to be the Head of Auror Office during the events of *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*?  Also, during the final duel between Dumbledore and Voldemort in the Ministry Atrium, the Aurors again were sent to arrest the captured Death Eaters in the aftermath of Battle of Department of Mysteries.  Where was Rufus Scrimgeour?

Why did the other Aurors show up in books 4 and 5 except Rufus Scrimgeour?  I recall from *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince* that Rufus was first introduced as the new Minister after sacking of Cornelius Fudge.  So, that means in book 6, Rufus seemed to have come out of nowhere.  So, where was Rufus before book 6?

Comment: Possibly in the imagination of J K Rowling.

Comment: Scrimgeour was the HEAD of the Aurors.  He wouldn't be expected to go on many field missions because he has to coordinate and is responsible for them all.

Comment: Still looking for Sirius in Timbucktoo

Comment: Well, you don't usually bring the head of the FBI to arrest a major criminal, but neither do you usually bring the President or the Secretary of Education so who are we to question the comings and goings of wizards?

Answer (score 5):

Probably looking for

> the mass murderer "Sirius Black"

Wherever Kingsley Shacklebolt sent him.

Scrimgeour was Head of the Auror office which means  he would have to undertake more important missions than "expelling a schoolboy" he would be working with Kingsley to pinpoint Sirius's location. Timbucktoo(or somewhere similar) apparently.